# Uninstall Windows Service from Deployment package

Tags: windows, visual-studio, deployment, service

I know that you can install your Windows Service via the VS deployment system which I've done.  But how do you deploy updates after that? Each time I deploy a new version, it says that the service already exists and exits.

I tried to add a little DOS CMD file with the following:
net stop [ServiceName]
sc delete [ServiceName]

It would work fine if I could just get to run it, but the custom scripts options in the Deployment system doesn't allow that file type.

How can I either a). Update my package on the clients pc or b). run that uninstall utility from within my installer so I can run the update?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards,

Storm

Answer (score 2):

If the service is already installed, all you need to do is NET STOP it, replace the exe, then NET START the service.